# Sharepoint 2010. Strange behavior in intranet: ip address vs dns name 

Tags: 2010

I have Sharepoint site published in Intranet. Most of the time I configure modules and site collection via **http://myserver** link. But some users have to use ip address: **http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx**

Users that access site via ip address observe strange behavior - children sites menus work inappropriate and some services look misconfigured.

How can I solve this issue?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check your alternate access mappings and also verify that the server is correctly registered in the DNS.